# Unexpected behavior for Express route regex generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I'm writing a route in Express that should match URLs of the form `/DDMMMYYYY`, such as `/01JUN2017` or `/31JUL2014`. My route is

```
app.get('/:date(\d{2}(JUN|JUL)\d{4})', ...);
```

but no expected URLS are matching.

According to [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/), this route is getting compiled to

```
/^\/(\d{2}\(JUN|JUL)\d\{4\}\)(?:\/(?=$))?$/i
```

which tells me that it is forcing a literal interpretation of the parenthesis before JUN, and the curly braces around 4. How can I tell Express to use these as special characters instead of literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define groups within groups. There is [an open issue about it](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/95).

Anyway, especifically for your case, you can do a workaround like:

```
app.get('/:date(\d{2}JU[NL]\d{4})', ...);
```